# Split a String and store into a List/Array in Outlook Macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm writing a macro to read through emails and parse the Body. For this, I need to split by newline character.

I wrote -

```
Dim stringList As Variant
Set stringList = Split(myMessage.Body, vbLf)
Debug.Print stringList(0)
```

But it says type mismatch. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use `Set` to assign the array returned by the `Split()` function to your `stringList` variable. The `Set` keyword is used to [assign an object reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/set-statement).
- It's better to declare the `stringList` as an array of String instead of a `Variant` since you already know the type of the value to be assigned.
- One more thing, you might want to split the string using `vbNewLine` instead of `vbLf`.

This should work:

```
Sub SplitMsgBody()
    Dim stringList() As String
    stringList = Split(myMessage.Body, vbNewLine) 'or vbLf depending on your requirements.

    For Each s In stringList
        Debug.Print s
    Next
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.